# Designing REST API(s), more complicated objects or more requests?

Tags: rest

I have problem with REST API(s) for front-end GUI and am wondering which approach is better. Are there any design patterns for these types of problems?

```
uri: /users/list

response: [
    {   
        id: "1",
        name "Aaa",
        surname "Bbb",
        contactDetails: {
            telephone: "111-111-111"
            email: "mail@mail.pl"
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

OR

```
uri: /users/list
response: [
    {   
        id: "1",
        name "Aaa",
        surname "Bbb"
    },
    ...
]

uri: /emails/list?userIds=1,..
response: [
    {
        userId: "1",
        email: "mail@mail.pl"
    }
]

uri: /telephones/list?userIds=1,..
response: [
    {
        userId: "1",
        telephone: "111-111-111"
    }
]
```

and it's the same for a single user:

```
uri : users/{id}
uri : users/{id}/emails
uri : users/{id}/telephones
```

============== Extended class model =================================
Below I paste JSON classes designed for question needs.

```
SystemPart : {
    id   : "sp2",
    name : "UserAdministration",
    parentSystemPart : {
        id : "sp1",
        name : "Administration",
        ...
    }
    ...
}

SystemPermission : {
    permissionType : "MODERATOR",
    systemParts    : [ // list of SystemPart
        {
            id   : "sp1",
            name : "UserAdministration",
            parentSystemPart:{...}
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
}

User: {
    id  : "u1",
    name    : "a",
    surname : "b",
    contactDetails : {
        telephone : "111-111-111"
        email     : "mail@mail.com"
    },
    identityCard : {
        idType : "Id",
        number : "321"
    }
    systemPermissions : [ // list of SystemPermission
        {
            permissionType  : "MODERATOR",
            systemParts : [...]
        },
        ...
    ]
}

MapPoint : {
    id : "mp1",
    x : 11.11,
    y : 22.22,
    createdBy : { // User
        id : "u1",
        ...
        systemPermission : [...]
    }
}
```

GUI client would like to show map point data with only it's author name, and surname
and now api for list of MapPoints

```
/map-points/list?x=11.00&y=22.00&d=5.0
```

other part of GUI would like to get list of users with its permissions

```
/users/list?page=0&size=5
```

In my opinion problem is in map-points list api which JSON is to big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with the **first** approach. The `User` class is pretty small and I don't see any benefits to calling the service separately for contact details.

Ensure that the client can **filter** the results based on every parameter, that way it is easy for the user of your API to get exactly what he/she wants.

For e.g. `/users/list` will get back everything which is perfect if there are relatively small number of users in the list and it's better to **eagerly cache** them all to improve client's performance.

```
uri: /users/list

response: [
{   
    id: "1",
    name "Aaa",
    surname "Bbb",
    contactDetails: {
        telephone: "111-111-111"
        email: "mail@mail.pl"
    }
},
...
]
```

If the number of users are significantly large, make sure the list can be filtered down to a small quantity based on every(*or at least the significant ones like last name*) parameter and the client can call your service for specific users and lazily load them as and when needed.

```
uri: /users/list?surname=Bbb
```

or

```
uri: /users/list?id=1
```

should get back:

```
response: [
{   
    id: "1",
    name "Aaa",
    surname "Bbb",
    contactDetails: {
        telephone: "111-111-111"
        email: "mail@mail.pl"
    }
}
]
```

Comment: List APIs will be pageable by page and limit parameters, so number of records it's not a problem. My problem is in size of single object (number of it's fields and nested objects). Where is the border, when large object should be splitted to smaller. It's especially significant for list API's where JSON object can be (in my opinion unnecessarily) very big.

Comment: In your case the `JSON` object has two more `String` fields wrapped in a `ContactDetail` class. I think it's much more expensive for the client to repeatedly call the service when he/she can get it all in one go. Having said that, if the contact fields are **rarely ever** used, it might be worth the added trouble.

Comment: The discussion about the size of JSON object would be more significant if you had **huge** classes inside each list item. In your case, I don't think it's very significant.

Comment: Above classes are just for this question needs, in my project there are many much bigger classes with many nested objects and I'm wondering where is the border to split them into smaller for list APIs needs. I thought that it can be any design patterns for this type of problems.

Comment: Imagine that I have, for example point on map. Every point is created by user and contains self position on map, description, and maybe some other nested objects. Every user is friend of any other user. Now I would like to get list of map points. Should json list contains full user data (with its friends) or maybe only it's ID, or maybe except ID some other additional fields? And that same for other nested objects, how split them into smaller and correct parts.

Comment: @user2860204, if you're thinking about splitting huge classes into smaller ones for your API's needs, you probably need to take a hard look at whether your existing classes are god classes or not. Make sure that none of your classes violate the single responsibility principle and if you find yourself asking whether they do, it's probably true.

Comment: @user2860204, Having said that, in general, what you need to provide in a single REST call is **dependent on how the client will use it**, in your case the GUI. If he needs the map data often, there is no point in making the client request repeatedly.

Comment: If you are talking about single responsibility in my opinion above user and contact details classes violates this principle. If you will tell that no I have next question. Does the mentioned map point class can contain user data too, insted just it's ID? I believe that somebody tell me about some design rules, because client usage can change in future but APIs shouldn't. And there can be more different clients, mobile, web, etc... with different needs

Comment: @user2860204, The `User` class is merely a data structure that contains name, identifiers and contact details. It has one responsibility and it's doing it just fine. If you can link the code for your `Map` class that you're talking about, I can try to understand your point better.

Comment: Ok I designed some new class model. Please look at the qustion again. Thank you

Comment: @user2860204, Create a separate `CondensedUser` class that only has `id`, `firstName` and `lastName` fields and include an instance of `CondensedUser` (instead of `User`) in your `MapPoint` class. That way, you'll have a much smaller `JSON`, and front-end logic can deal with matching `User`(s) by their `id`(s).

Comment: Thank you It's the way that I resolve it now. But is it good that In my solution User extends CondesedUser? Sometimes when requirments change I must move some field's from User to CondensedUser. And could you tell me is it good that parentSystemPart field of SystemParent object have full data instead just ID?

Comment: @user2860204, `CondensedUser` should **not** extend `User`. A should inherit B only if A *is* B and A is a **logical extension** of B, for instance a `Car` can extend `Vehicle`. I don't think `User` is a logical extension of a `CondensedUser` and there shouldn't be any inheritance involved. `CondensedUser` is merely a convenience class that provides a more condensed version of `User`.

Comment: @user2860204, I think it's good to have the entire `SystemPart` instance as a `parentSystemPart`. If I went through your code and I saw that the `parentSystemPart` variable was a `SystemPart` in itself, it would make logical sense. If it were a `CondensedSystemPart`, I would be slightly confused and I don't think making that `JSON` smaller is worth it in this case. I would **preserve the actual hierarchical relationship** in that `JSON`.

Comment: @user2860204, On a side note, if you found my answer and follow up comments satisfactory, I would appreciate it if you accepted my answer, given that I've invested quite some time in this. But do it **only if you're satisfied** with my answer, thanks in advance.